# How to use split() function when spacing is different?

Tags: java, split

I am trying to dump data to mysql using java programming.

01:13:01  IST     CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
01:13:02  IST     all      7.56      0.00      1.01      0.00      0.00     91.44
01:13:03  IST     all     13.03      0.00      1.25      1.25      0.00     84.46

this is my sample data. Here spacing between data is different so while using split(" ") some data are missing since different spacing should be done in order to get all the data.

please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str.split("\\s+")` covers all spacing of all lenghts.

Answer (score 2):

Use below regex :

```
String[] ans = str.split("\\s+");
```

FYI : [Here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) is a good tutorial for regex.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following REGEX. It will cover different spacings.

```
str = "Hello    I'm   your     String";
String[] splitStr = str.split("\\s+");
```

Answer (score 0):

If the whitespace is only spaces, add a `+`:

```
String[] cols = str.split(" +");
```

A plus sign means "one *or more* of the preceding term", so `" +"` means one or more spaces.